# Calculating poll votes

Tags: php, mysql

I got a poll on my website and 5 stars rating:

```
1 star - 1 (worst)
2 stars - 2
3 stars - 3
4 stars - 4
5 stars - 5 (best)
```

Now, how should I store the poll records in MySQL? How to calculate them?
Default rate value is 5, but if user would rate it 1 star, it should change this value to 1 instead and then start to calculating it somehow... First I need an idea on how to store the votes in my database. You probably have more experience with that.

Comment: You vote on what? posts? users? comments? Who does the votes? Users? Registered users? Anonymous users?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use "no opinion" as default and cast the vote only when the user clicks a button?

Comment: @Truth Its a vote on the games. And a vote can be submitted by the anonymous users.

Answer (score 1):

Store votes in a separate table, this way you will have record on who has voted.

`user_id, topic_id , vote, date` will be enough for now. Calculating is easy sum all votes  divide by the total number of votes related to the topic. This will give you the average . In case you want it to show as 1-5 you can `round()` it. In order not to do this calculation every time you load a topic you can store it in a field in the topics table and update that field each time you add/remove record from the votes table.

Answer (score 0):

Just store the votes in an integer field (1 to 5) in the table, combined with other info (eg to make sure the user can vote only once).

When you want to show the result, you use the cast votes, eg to calculate an average, or other statistics.
Recalculating (and storing) the statistics after each vote is cast, is also possible but not really required, unless you have much more page views than votes cast then it might result in less resource usage. (This also depending on the complexity of your statical calculations of course)

Comment: Thanks. When you upvote my post I'll upvote your back because I need `10` reputation to upvote `:D`.

Comment: You already accepted my answer, so upvoting not not necessary (unless you feel very strong about it of course)